# Mean of yearly / monthly expanding window in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a large dataset where I have hundreds of columns of financial price data with datetimeindex as index.

Similarly shaped random data can be generated with the following code:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'), index=pd.date_range("20180101", periods=1000))
             A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
2018-01-01  23   0   6  19   2  69   2  73
2018-01-02  30  46  46  62  48  79  37  38
2018-01-03  69  95  22  87  62  80   8  82
2018-01-04  89  76  25  65   7   2  42  74
2018-01-05  30  31  33  88  62  48  70  42
...         ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
2020-09-22  60  66  85  77  82   3  22  51
2020-09-23  12   7  32  68  84  55  23  92
2020-09-24  30  93  18  79  87   4  65  36
2020-09-25  57   8  17  30  75  41  22  57
2020-09-26  46  81  69  22  73  28   5  18
```

If I want to get rolling mean, I can use

```
df.rolling(10).mean()
```

To get expanding mean I can use

```
df.expanding().mean()
```

I want to get an expanding monthly and yearly mean for all the columns (expanding mean that resets at year change or month change). How can I do that?

The result should contain the same index and columns as the original dataframe.

Comment: plz provide [mre]

Comment: Minimal data generation example added.

Comment: When providing input as a random sample, also provide the seed.

Comment: It really doesn't matter in this case. That is a random example. Please do not nitpick at random questions.

Comment: It is a legitimate and essential requirement to provide a seed when providing input as a random sample.
This is because it ensures that you provide a reproducible example and makes it easy to verify the answer.
**Do not think that your question is only valid for you.**
If you are not going to respond to the other person's request, it is not right to ask a question on SO.
Furthermore, random samples are generally not [mre], and your example is no exception. They are generally examples that are made because they are tedious to create.

Comment: In this question it is in no way essential to provide a seed for a random dataframe generation example. The example was provided to give an example of the dataframe shape and content. Please do not nitpick as I said.

Comment: In a [mre], both minimal and reproducible are important.
Requesting a seed in a sample is neither an unreasonable request nor a request that deserves to be ridiculed.
I would have created an example like the one I added to the answer. Then you can easily create the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.max_rows = 6

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'), index=pd.date_range("20180101", periods=1000))
```

df

```
             A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
2018-01-01  44  47  64  67  67   9  83  21
2018-01-02  36  87  70  88  88  12  58  65
2018-01-03  39  87  46  88  81  37  25  77
...         ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
2020-09-24  96  34  58  30  53  36  26  40
2020-09-25   0  17  58  95  87  32  17  71
2020-09-26   7  53  16  30  30  34  25  82
```

**Code**

expanding in year

```
out = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('Y')).expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
```

out:

```
               A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
2018-01-01 44.00 47.00 64.00 67.00 67.00  9.00 83.00 21.00
2018-01-02 40.00 67.00 67.00 77.50 77.50 10.50 70.50 43.00
2018-01-03 39.67 73.67 60.00 81.00 78.67 19.33 55.33 54.33
...          ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
2020-09-24 49.70 48.61 47.22 50.63 47.92 50.44 47.70 48.70
2020-09-25 49.52 48.49 47.26 50.80 48.07 50.37 47.59 48.78
2020-09-26 49.36 48.51 47.14 50.72 48.00 50.31 47.50 48.90
```

expanding in month (period 'Y' -> 'M')

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
```

---

**chk result**

df.loc['2020']

```
             A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
2020-01-01  60  39  45  33  94  99  60  34
2020-01-02  66  29  39  63  22  99  53  64
2020-01-03  26  68  43  47   9  70  29   5
...         ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
2020-09-24  96  34  58  30  53  36  26  40
2020-09-25   0  17  58  95  87  32  17  71
2020-09-26   7  53  16  30  30  34  25  82
```

out.loc['2020']

```
               A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
2020-01-01 60.00 39.00 45.00 33.00 94.00 99.00 60.00 34.00
2020-01-02 63.00 34.00 42.00 48.00 58.00 99.00 56.50 49.00
2020-01-03 50.67 45.33 42.33 47.67 41.67 89.33 47.33 34.33
...          ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
2020-09-24 49.70 48.61 47.22 50.63 47.92 50.44 47.70 48.70
2020-09-25 49.52 48.49 47.26 50.80 48.07 50.37 47.59 48.78
2020-09-26 49.36 48.51 47.14 50.72 48.00 50.31 47.50 48.90
```

expanding by year

---

Providing an example like `df1` will satisfy both the minimal and reproducible conditions, and it will also be easy to provide the desired output.

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-02', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20], [20, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70], [80, 90], [10, 20]], index=idx, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

df1

```
             A   B
2019-01-01  10  20
2019-01-02  20  30
2019-02-01  40  50
2019-02-02  60  70
2020-01-01  80  90
2020-01-02  10  20
```

Comment: This answers to the yearly part (half of the question), not the monthly part.

Comment: @mikkom Of course, you can change the period to monthly if you want. `df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).expanding().mean().droplevel(0)`

Comment: Wouldn't that group all the months together regardless of the year?

Edit: actually it does not. Thank you. However I cannot mark this as answered as it does not answer the full question.

Comment: @mikkom If you want to combine January 2019 and January 2020 into one, regardless of the year, you can do so. However, there seems to be no reason to do such a thing in general.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid as grouping by index.month does exactly that but the to_period works correctly (it outputs index in form of YYYY-MM) so it works correctly.

Comment: @mikkom If you provide the code to create a year, even a beginner in Pandas can easily change the period to monthly, and I have also provided the code to change it in the comments.
It seems like a poor excuse to say that you cannot accept the answer because it is half the answer.
The premise of SO is to create answers that are helpful to everyone, and the questioner also adopts the answer to let others know that it is a working and appropriate code.
To be helpful to everyone,

Comment: It would be really easy to edit your answer to answer the whole question so people would not need to read the comments below to get the full answer. Please edit the answer to provide the answer to the full question so I can approve the answer. I cannot approve a partial answer that requires the reader to read the whole comment section to get the full answer. This is my final answer to this thread, you can do as you wish with your answer, I'll approve it if it answers the question fully.

Comment: @mikkom It's already provided in the answer. It's been like that since 22 minutes ago